# App crashing without Tombsone (Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x20 in tid 23873)

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm getting the infamous fatal signal 11 crash from a JNI library I am using. However, the crash is not providing a tombstone, only offering these messages:

```
02-03 21:45:41.857 3080-3080/? E/DEBUG: Failed to find a valid tombstone, default to using tombstone 0.
02-03 21:45:41.857 3080-3080/? E/DEBUG: failed to open tombstone file '/data/tombstones/tombstone_00': No such file or directory
02-03 21:45:41.857 3080-3080/? I/DEBUG: Skipping tombstone write, nothing to do.
```

Is there anything else I can use to find out why the crash happens?

Comment: Q: Is your device rooted?  Q: Have you run out of disk space?  Look here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/161867/running-out-of-storage-space-data-log-directory-not-found

Comment: It is rooted, it is not out of space.

Comment: Q: And the directory and file (if the latter exists) are world-read/write?  PS: `fault addr 0x20` doesn't sound like a valid memory address :(

Comment: I'm not sure. How do I find out? I know so little about the using the NDK, I thought it the native layer was supposed to generate the tombstone. I'm using the open source version of Android and a library made by someone elsewhere in my company.

Comment: Short answer: I probably can't be of much help.  Sorry :(  But... 1) An "address" is usually a large, 32- (or 64-bit) hex number.  A value like `0x20` is usually either the number "32" (for an arithmetic), or an ASCII 0x20 "space" character (for a text string).  It's almost certainly *NOT* a memory address.  2) SUGGESTION: If you have a debugger than can step in to your C/C++ (JNI) code ... then use it.  Even without a core dump (and corresponding stack trace), you can probably "guess" likely places to set breakpoints and step through the code.